# Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 4

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I run my docker image on a virtual server and get this error, you have an idea why, it works for me locally, and the virtual server has the same characteristics.

```
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[WARNING] Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 4
```

I tried running the image with other commands but still the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.